# Input elements pushing content outside of flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm having trouble with understanding what is happening with the flexbox sidebar setup. I will attach image to show the problem, but basically I want the inputs to take up the remaining space after the right sidebar takes up 300px. For some reason the inputs pushes the sidebar out onto the side. Without the input rows, it works perfectly. The blue overlay is the max-width of the content. The green background is the leftColumn and the red background is the rightColumn (sidebar).

Just also wondering if this is the best way of setting this up, or is there a better way to achieve this. [image]

```css
    .columns{
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
    }
    .leftColumn{ 
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      background-color: green;
      flex-grow: 1;
    }
    .rightColumn{
      background-color: red;
      min-width: 300px;
    }
    .row{
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      margin-bottom: 12px;
    }
    .inputContainer{
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .label{
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
      color: $light-grey;
      transform: translate(16px, 16px);
      font-size: 16px;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .input{
      height: 50px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      margin-right: 12px;
      padding: 16px;
      padding-top: 26px;
      padding-bottom: 4px;
      border: none;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 1px rgba(235, 235, 235, 1);
      -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 1px rgba(235, 235, 235, 1);
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 1px rgba(235, 235, 235, 1);
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      font-size: 22px;
      font-weight: 500 !important;
      font-family: $primary-font;
      color: $primary-dark;
    }
    .input:focus{
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 1px rgba(189, 42, 245, 1);
      -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 1px rgba(189, 42, 245, 1);
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 1px rgba(189, 42, 245, 1);
      outline: none;
    }
    .textArea{
      @extend .input;
      width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
 <div className={styles.addItem}>
        <h3 className={styles.heading}>Add Line Item</h3>
        <div className={styles.columns}>
          <div className={styles.leftColumn}>
            <div className={styles.row}>
              <div className={styles.inputContainer}>
                <label htmlFor="date" className={styles.label}>
                  Date
                </label>
                <input id="date" className={styles.input} />
              </div>
              <div className={styles.inputContainer}>
                <label htmlFor="hours" className={styles.label}>
                  Hours
                </label>
                <input id="hours" className={styles.input} type="number" />
              </div>
              <div className={styles.inputContainer}>
                <label htmlFor="category" className={styles.label}>
                  Category
                </label>
                <input id="category" className={styles.input} />
              </div>
              <div className={styles.inputContainer}>
                <label htmlFor="rate" className={styles.label}>
                  Rate
                </label>
                <input id="rate" className={styles.input} />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className={styles.row}>
              <div className={styles.inputContainer}>
                <label htmlFor="rate" className={styles.label}>
                  Notes
                </label>
                <input id="rate" className={styles.textArea} type="textarea" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className={styles.rightColumn}>Right Col</div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In the .inputContainer class in css i have added the **display: flex** and afterwards it is working fine.

```css
.columns {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.leftColumn {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: green;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.rightColumn {
  background-color: red;
  min-width: 300px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.inputContainer {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.label {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  color: $light-grey;
  transform: translate(16px, 16px);
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 98%;
}

.input {
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-right: 12px;
  padding: 16px;
  padding-top: 26px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  border: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 1px rgba(235, 235, 235, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 1px rgba(235, 235, 235, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 1px rgba(235, 235, 235, 1);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 500 !important;
  font-family: $primary-font;
  color: $primary-dark;
}

.input:focus {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 1px rgba(189, 42, 245, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 1px rgba(189, 42, 245, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 1px rgba(189, 42, 245, 1);
  outline: none;
}

.textArea {
  @extend .input;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="addItem">
  <h3 class="heading">Add Line Item</h3>
  <div class="columns">
    <div class="leftColumn">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="inputContainer">
          <label htmlFor="date" class="label">
              Date
            </label>
          <input id="date" class="input" />
        </div>
        <div class=inputContainer>
          <label htmlFor="hours" class="label">
              Hours
            </label>
          <input id="hours" class="input" type="number" />
        </div>
        <div class="inputContainer">
          <label htmlFor="category" class="label">
              Category
            </label>
          <input id="category" class="input" />
        </div>
        <div class="inputContainer">
          <label htmlFor="rate" class="label">
              Rate
            </label>
          <input id="rate" class="input" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="inputContainer">
          <label htmlFor="rate" class="label">
              Notes
            </label>
          <input id="rate" class="textArea" type="textarea" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rightColumn">Right Col</div>
  </div>
</div>
```